# Restrict sheet owner from accessing Range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-addon

I'm creating an add-on for google sheets. The add-on will be used mostly on sheets created by it. Is it possible to restrict the user(owner of the sheet) from editing ranges? However, the add-on should still be able to edit it

I'm new to app script. This is my first project. When I try to protect ranges in Google sheets manually, it doesn't allow me to remove the owner(the only user) to be removed. Is it possible to achieve this using the Protection class?

Comment: No.............

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much avout google sheets, but instead of keeping the owner from editing, why don't you store the value and set it back every time the owner changes the value?

Comment: To be explicit, store it in ``PropertiesService``

Comment: I am trying to avoid onEdit as there will be a performance hit and it will also increase the Trigger Quota